# Regex find digits after String

Tags: java, regex

From the two urls

```
https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/829684271812067328

https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/829684271812067328/
```

I want to extract the String `829684271812067328` in Java. 
My attempt was

```
\\/status\\/([\\d]+)
```

but this does not allow anything before `/status` or after the digits (`/`).

Whats the solution to this?

Comment: Show us your java code

Comment: You might want to show us how you're applying that regex on the input. Besides that `/status/(\d+)` should be sufficient (in Java strings you'd need to escape the backslashes of course).

Comment: @Sentry I indeed used matches() instead of find(), thanks!

Comment: your url can contain an int in the middle or not?

Comment: this part you want to get can contain another character or just numbers?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to extract data (rather than validate the url format), I'd use the following regex :

```
(\\d+)/?$
```

And extract the first group of the result.

It matches a non-empty sequence of digits that can be followed by a `/` and must be found at the end of the matched text.